# Disable transitive project reference in .NET Standard 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm writing an MVC website using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

In the ASP.NET Core project (let's call it `Web`), I reference a .NET Standard 2 project in the same solution (let's call it `Service`). The `Service` project also references a third .NET Standard 2 library in the solution (let's call this one `Business`). The `Business` project declares a type called `Model`.

The problem is that I can use `Model` in the `Web` project (i.e. the compiler sees the type `Model` and I can do `var a = new Model();`) as if the `Web` project has referenced `Business`, but it actually only has a reference to `Service`.

How can I hide `Model` from `Web`? Is this a new feature in ASP.NET Core 2 or all .NET Standard projects are like this?

**Edit**

As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428571), this is due to transitive project references which is a new "feature" in .NET Standard, but how do I fix it?

Comment: I believe this is a feature of the new project formats (`project.json` and `csproj` now). Any nested reference is available directly inside the project (aka [transitive dependencies](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/200)). You may try [this way](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2313) to turn it off for a single reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitive references in .Net Core 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428571/transitive-references-in-net-core-1-1)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well my question was close to one marked as duplicate here but to solve it requires different tactic.

Thanks to comment from "Federico Dipuma" and the answer given [here](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2313) I was able to solve this problem.

You should edit the `Service.csproj` file and add `PrivateAssets="All"` to `ProjectReference` keys you don't want to flow to top.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Business.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: nice and clear - just to underline what you've said (but which i managed to overlook first time).  Reference chain is Web->Services->Business and it is in SERVICES that you need to add the PrivateAssets="All" to hide Business from Web (I was putting it in the Web->Services ProjectReference which wasn't working - I just needed to read your answer more carefully!)

Answer (score 47):

## Transitive project references (`ProjectReference`)

Transitive project references are new feature of SDK-style csproj ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk),[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#sdk-attribute)) format used in .NET Core/.NET >= 5. You can also use this csproj for old .NET Framework projects ([1](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017),[2](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/),[3](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpgradingAnExistingNETProjectFilesToTheLeanNewCSPROJFormatFromNETCore.aspx)) but with some [exceptions](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2670#issuecomment-589976895).

In this SDK-style format project references (represented by `<ProjectReference>` entry in .csproj file) are transitive. This is different to old non-SDK .csproj used previously.

But you have three options to go back to old non-transitive behavior.

1. Use `<DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>` property in .csproj that references projects for which you don't want their transitive dependencies to be visible by compiler.

   In your case you can add it to *Web* project. (first project that reference other projects, *Web* -> *Service* -> *Business*)

   You can also set this behavior globally for all .csprojs by doing it in [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file that you put in the root folder that contains your source.

   ```xml
   <Project>
       <PropertyGroup>
           <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
       </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

   With this file you basically have old project reference behaviour. Useful when you do migration of old .NET Framework solution that uses old csproj format to new SDK-style .csprojs.
2. On the project that you reference you can set which dependencies shouldn't *flow*  further when the project is referenced. You use `PrivateAssets="All"` attribute on `<ProjectReference>` for this. So for example you can edit *Service*.csproj like this:

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
       <ProjectReference Include="..\Business.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

   This is more flexible and fine-grained approach. You can control with particular transitive project references should be visible when the project is referenced.
3. Use [`ItemDefinitionGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-definitions?view=vs-2019#item-metadata-default-values) to define default `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` metadata for all `ProjectReference`s. You can also define it in *Directory.Build.props* file if you want to apply it globally to all projects.

   ```xml
   <ItemDefinitionGroup>
       <ProjectReference>
           <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
       </ProjectReference>
   </ItemDefinitionGroup>
   ```

   The effect would be the same as setting `<ProjectReference Include="..."> <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets> </ProjectReference>` (or `PrivateAssets="All"` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019#specify-metadata-as-attributes)  on all `ProjectReferences` entries.

   The difference from using 1. approach (`DisableTransitiveProjectReferences`) is that if you explicitly define `PrivateAssets` metadata on `ProjectReference` item then this value is used. You can think of using `ItemDefinitionGroup` as a way to provide default value of `PrivateAssets` metadata it it is not provided explicitly.

What should you use? It depends what you prefer. If you are used to old csproj behavior or want to migrate old solution to .NET Core then using  `DisableTransitiveProjectReferences` or `ItemDefinitionGroup` in your *Directory.Build.props* is the easiest solution.

---

## Nuget references (`PackageReference`) are also transitive by default.

This is not strictly answering your question but is something that you should be aware too.

If you are using new [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) format for nuget packages (and you probably do because this is the default in new SDK-style csproj files) then you should also be aware that these references are transitive. If your project references another project (with `ProjectReference`) that references nuget package (with `PackageReference`) then your project will also reference this nuget package.

[image: Diagram showing ProjectA referencing ProjectB which references Newtonsoft.Jon package]

Here *ProjectA* will have implicit reference to *Newtosoft.Json* library.

Unfortunately there is [no DisableTransitivePackagesReferences](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11803) for package references. But you can use [PrivateAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) metadata like you did for `ProjectReference` in 2nd option or use `ItemDefinitionGroup` like you did in 3rd option.

That's why if you want to disable transitive dependencies both for project and package references for all projects then this is how your *Directory.build.props* file should look like:

```xml
<Project>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <ProjectReference>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </ProjectReference>
        <PackageReference>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

(source: I learned about this technique from this [blog](https://curia.me/net-core-transitive-references-and-how-to-block-them/) )

or

```xml
<Project>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
        <PackageReference>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hey Mariusz, is there a way of doing it from the referencing project? 
This here modifies the project _being_ referenced, not the project doing the referencing :/

Answer (score 11):

All the above answers currently do not work for nuget package dependencies.

For the following library project (PrivateAssets="all"):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>Roy</Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The following nuspec file will be produced:

```xml
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyLib</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Roy</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Notice how "Newtonsoft.Json" is not even specified as a dependency.
This will obviously not work as Visual Studio will not even be aware of that dependency and the consuming project will fail to resolved "Newtonsoft.Json" at runtime.

The correct answer is setting `PrivateAssets="compile"`.

Which will result in the following nuspec file:

```xml
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyLib</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Roy</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" include="Runtime,Build,Native,ContentFiles,Analyzers,BuildTransitive" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

This will prevent the consuming project from accessing the Newtonsoft.Json namespace in code, while compiling and copying all the required assemblies to allow the "encapsulating" library work.

Comment: For me i must use PrivateAssets="compile", with build i've access to namespace

Comment: @JuanR, seems you are right, I made so many tests I probably got confused by the local nuget package caching and the right solution. I corrected my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. With `PrivateAssets="all"`, the runtime indicates a missing library, which this answer explains why.