# why import unwanted dependent library in .net core 2?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created a simple example with below code. 
In my test project UI layer(.Net Core) I have a dependency to Business Layer and my Business Layer Reference to Data Layer.
My question is why UI can import Data Layer functionality without referencing to Data because I really don't want to import that !!

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data.Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.foo();//i have access to data layer !!

        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

[image: my project structure]

Comment: That's because your business layer has a reference to it and your classes are public. Its bad enough that you reference data layer directly from business layer. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709599/455493)

Comment: Tanks, it's worked.