# Is there a way in C# to restrict call to indirect referenced library/DLL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, n-tier-architecture, dll-reference

I have a project which is designed in 3-tier architecture. To keep it simple, I will simplify my case in traditionally 3-tiers, **Presentation** -> **Business Logic** -> **DAL**.

I have these 3 tiers in 3 different projects and so that I will have 1 startup executable and 2 DLL finally. However, I found that I can make call from **Presentation Layer** to **DAL Layer** even **DAL Layer Project** is not directly referenced by **Presentation Layer Project**.

May I know if there any way for me to restrict these indirect references calling? Or any way I can make sure other developer can't make such call?

Comment: See [Ioc/DI - Why do I have to reference all layers/assemblies in application's entry point?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612).

Answer (score 2):

`Presenation`-project should only reference `BusinessLogic`-project

`BusinessLogic` should only reference `DAL`.

I believe `Presentation` references both `BusinessLogic` and `DAL`.

Make sure that the `Presentation.csproj`-file looks something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
... (more stuff) ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BusinessLogic\BusinessLogic.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and does not contain a reference to the DAL-project.

Comment: Yes, I remember this is the behavior in .NET Framework... I don't know why I can reference `DAL` from `Presentation Layer` in .NET Core. I am sure that I do not get `Presentation Project` refer to `DAL`

Comment: If you try to instantiate a class from DAL in Presentation Layer, then it won't compile if you try (and you have your project references correct). 
But I believe Visual Studio, and Rider etc. have "Quick Fixes" for what they believe is "the problem" so that you easily can add a reference to the DAL-project.

Comment: seems the reason has been stated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709000/disable-transitive-project-reference-in-net-standard-2, but still thanks for your help!