# Stop F# from adding indirectly referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, f#, msbuild

I am using VS 2022 and when I create an F# project and solution it dumps all of the indirectly referenced assemblies from one other assemblies into the bin directory when I build the solution.

[image]

When I write the same program in C#, the build directory is clean, and only contains the built files plus the referenced assemblies that I told it to include (with Copy Local).

[image]

The assembly that references all of these others has its Private property marked as False in both projects, but F# still drags everything in.

[image]

Is this just an issue with how F# builds and references C# libraries?

I tried modifying the Private property and looked for other configuration items that might be applicable. I added the DLLs being added to the directory into the Project file, in hopes that it would not copy it, but it still does.

Here is the .csproj.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{B9485712-4A8F-4894-8268-003BC72149C3}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ConnectTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ConnectTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EllieMae.Encompass.AsmResolver">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\EllieMae.Encompass.AsmResolver.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EllieMae.Encompass.Runtime">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\EllieMae.Encompass.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EncompassObjects">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\EncompassObjects.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Here is the .fsproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework> 

    <WarnOn>3390;$(WarnOn)</WarnOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ClientServer">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\ClientServer.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EllieMae.Encompass.AsmResolver">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\EllieMae.Encompass.AsmResolver.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EllieMae.Encompass.Runtime">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\EllieMae.Encompass.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EncompassObjects">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\EncompassObjects.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you show full `.csrpoj` and `.fsproj` ?

Comment: @JL0PD project files added. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: C# uses legacy project format, F# version uses sdk-style format, which have different behavior. Probably if you convert C# project to newer format, you'll get same behavior as F# project. Then it will be question how to achieve desired on newer project format, which I don't know answer for

Answer (score 1):

You can add this property to the project to get the old behavior

```
    <DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>
```

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852224/7392598