# Prevent Visual Studio IntelliSense from Seeing References of NuGet Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, intellisense

## Environment

I have a .NET Standard library that references a particular NuGet package (ClosedXML). This NuGet package references other NuGet packages (in this case, DocumentFormat.OpenXml).

## Problem

As I type code (or copy and paste), IntelliSense frequently thinks I want the types of DocumentFormat.OpenXml, so it autocompletes for those types and adds those using statements. But I want nothing to do with DocumentFormat.OpenXml directly. I just want to use ClosedXML.

## Question

How can I prevent IntelliSense from suggesting I use the types of DocumentFormat.OpenXml? I only want to see the types of the libraries I reference directly.

## Secondary Question

What is the name of these references that are allowed to be made indirectly? For example, my code can reference types from DocumentFormat.OpenXml by virtue of the fact that I am referencing a project that references DocumentFormat.OpenXml. What is this reference called? I sometimes see the names "secondary reference" or "indirect reference."

Comment: To answer your secondary question, these are known as transitive references, if that helps you with searching for this kind of stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709000/disable-transitive-project-reference-in-net-standard-2 has some things you can try, though I'm not 100% sure any of them are exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewMcClement, for the information and for the link! I tried what I read there, and I guess those solutions have to be performed on the referenced project (in this case, ClosedXML). I started an issue with ClosedXML, and hopefully they'll change how they reference projects: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/2210